# Find a disconnected mount point

Tags: ubuntu

What is the easiest way/command to find a disconnected mount point?

I have a system running Ubuntu 14.04 with nfs and cifs mounts connected to it.

Comment: Did you try if they works in your case? Are the cifs in your own subnet or in another?

Answer (score 2):

I found some ways. About which is the most simple it's up to you:

1. `M=$(timeout 1 stat -t "/path/to/mountpoint" 2>&1) && echo "UP" || echo "DOWN"` The command `M=$(timeout 1 stat -t "/path/to/mountpoint" 2>&1)` will store the output in the variable `M` and will give the exit status accessible through `$?`.
   In the proposed version it will answer a cosy `UP` or `DOWN`.
   The `timeout 1` will kill that `stat` command and hence will kill its open file handle.
2. You can parse the output of `stat` in search of the keyword *"stale"*, better redirecting the *stderror*

   ```
   timeout 1 stat /path/to/my/mountpoint 2>&1 | grep -i "stale"
   ```

   Here again the `timeout 1` will kill that `stat` command and hence will kill its open file handle.
3. `rpcinfo` reports RPC information. The above should works too

   ```
   rpcinfo -t remote.system.net nfs > /dev/null 2>&1
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo Remote NFS share available.
   fi
   ```

**Further readings and inspirations :)**

- [How can I use read timeouts with stat?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751753/3569208)
- [Linux Shell Script: How to detect NFS Mount-point (or the Server) is dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17644527/3569208)